# Equality for 2 lists of different types

Tags: .net, linq, interface, equality

Let's assume we have 2 collections, at least IEnumerable to power on Linq (also assume .net 4.0):

```
List<T1> list1;  
List<T2> list2;
```

I can define equality between objects of type T1 and T2.

1. What is the best way (i.e. .net interface and Linq preferred) to verify if the 2 lists are equal (order of elements is not relevant).
2. How can I optimize this problem if I know that the objects T1 and T2 have an ID

Ex of T1 and T2:

```
class Device 
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
}

class DeviceInfo
{ 
    string Identifier;
    string FriendlyName;
    DateTime CreateDate;
}
```

Later edit:

The solution should involve some sort of equality comparer that I write and is generic enough. There may be cases where 2 objects have the same Id but different name, and comparison should then fail. For example:

```
static bool AreEqual(Device device, DeviceInfo deviceInfo)
{
     return device.Id == deviceInfo.Identifier &&
            device.Name == deviceInfo.FriendlyName;
}
```

Comment: `IEqualityComparer` is supposed to work on objects of the same type. You could make it accept two `object` parameters and try some casting or such, but don't: use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming .NET 4.0:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[];
Bar[] bars = new Bar[];

var areDifferent = foos.Zip(bars, (foo, bar) => foo.Id == bar.Id).Any(b => !b);
```

A better solution would also check that `foos` and `bars` have the same length, and that none of the elements are `null` as well. And of course, this example assumes that the collections are already sorted by `Id`.

**Update:**

So, here's the "better solution" in all its LINQy detail:

```
var areDifferent = foos.Count() != bars.Count() ||
                   foos.OrderBy(foo => foo.Id)
                   .Zip(
                       bars.OrderBy(bar => bar.Id),
                       (foo, bar) => foo != null && bar != null && foo.Id == bar.Id)
                   .Any(b => !b);
```

Comment: The OP says "order of elements is not relevant". This will give false negatives if the sequences are equivalent but ordered differently.

Comment: Zip works, but it took me a few minutes to read the code. Why not do SequenceEquals ?

Comment: @Bogdan: To use `SequenceEquals` the collections need to be of the same type, or derive from a common base, or implement the same interface. The `Zip`-based solution allows you to write your comparison function as an inline lambda, and does not have these requirements.

Comment: Good point, it was not evident from your code that the condition there should be extended to include the comparison function.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Device> devices = ...
List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfos = ...

var deviceIds = devices.Select(d => d.Id)
                       .OrderBy(id => id);

var deviceInfoIds = deviceInfos.Select(d => d.Identifier)
                               .OrderBy(id => id);

bool areEqual = deviceIds.SequenceEqual(deviceInfoIds);
```

If duplicate Ids are not possible, set semantics will come in handy:

```
bool areEqual = !devices.Select(d => d.Id)
                        .Except(deviceInfos.Select(d => d.Identifier))
                        .Any();
```

I would recommend if possible that you declare an `IHasId` (or similar) interface and get both types to implement it.

**EDIT**:

In response to your edit, you *could* write an `IEqualityComparer` implementation that did what you wanted. It would look really ugly; you would have to do a speculative cast from *each* argument to DeviceInfo / Device to try and extract an identifier out. I wouldn't really recommend this; it's a bad idea for an equality-comparer to compare objects of completely different types. It would be a *lot* easier if you got each type to implement a common interface that provided an identifier.

Comment: You have reduced the problem to comparing 2 lists of strings. If not IEquatable<T> / IEqualityComparer, what else?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing 2 lists of strings is not very complicated. Both solutions based on ordering the lists have N log (N) complexity not taking into account the size of the string. The better solution is (pseudocode), complexity is N:

```
create a dictionary<string, int>

foreach element in list1
if element is in dict
 dict[element]++;
else
 dict[element] = 1;

foreach element in list2
if element is in dict
 dict[element]--;
else 
 return NOT_EQUAL;

if dict has only 0 values lists are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the difference between two different list: 
If they have any common property.

```
 var differentItems = List<Type1>.Select(d => d.Name)
                        .Except(List<Type2>.Select(d => d.Name));
```